# Superspace Uncertainty Principle

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, supersymmetry, fermions, grassmann-numbers

Do the "operator for translations in superspace" and the "position in superspace operator" follow an uncertainty principle?  How "real" is [superspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superspace)?  Aside from being weird (and possibly just a "mathematical trick") is superspace really just an extension of space on the same footing as real space (with off-shell degrees of freedom)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Well, no measuring device is going to measure a [Grassmann-odd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number)$^1$ number. A measuring device can only produce real outputs $\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

However, one can measure a [fermionic condensate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermionic_condensate), i.e. an expectation value $\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ of an composite bosonic Hermitian operator, where each term is built from an even number of elementary fermionic operators, typically two.

2) It also makes sense to e.g. consider [canonical anticommutation relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCR_and_CAR_algebras) (CAR) for fermionic operators in complete analogy with [canonical commutation relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) (CRR) for bosonic operators. As is well-known, CCRs can be viewed as the source/origin of [Heisenberg's uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) (HUP).

It is natural to ponder if there exists a fermionic HUP? It turns out that we can only see a HUP effect of CARs indirectly. We first have to construct composite bosonic Hermitian operator observables, say $A$ and $B$, build out of some elementary fermionic (and bosonic) operators that obeys CARs (and CCRs). Again, the composite bosonic operators $A$ and $B$ must necessarily both consist of an even number of elementary fermionic operators in each of their terms. The uncertainty

$$\langle ( \Delta A )^{2} \rangle \langle ( \Delta B )^{2} \rangle ~\geq~ \frac{1}{4} | \langle [ A,B ] \rangle |^{2} $$

of $A$ and $B$ is in principle measurable, and can be linked to the pertinent CARs (and CCRs).

3) *An Example.* Consider Hermitian elementary fermions $c^i$, $i=1, \ldots, n$, with CAR

$$\tag{1} \{c^i, c^j\}~=~ \hbar g^{ij}{\bf 1} , 
\qquad g^{ji}~=~g^{ij}~\in~\mathbb{R},  $$

and a fermionic condensate

$$ \chi^{ij}~:=~\frac{\mathrm{i}}{2}\langle [c^i, c^j] \rangle, 
\qquad \chi^{ji}~=~-\chi^{ij}~\in~\mathbb{R}. $$

Let the two composite bosonic operators be

$$ A~=~ \frac{\mathrm{i}}{4}\alpha_{ij} [c^i, c^j] , 
\qquad \alpha_{ji}=-\alpha_{ij}~\in~\mathbb{R}, $$

and

$$ B~=~ \frac{\mathrm{i}}{4}\beta_{ij} [c^i, c^j] , 
\qquad \beta_{ji}=-\beta_{ij}~\in~\mathbb{R}. $$

Then one may calculate that

$$\tag{2}  \langle [ A,B ] \rangle~=~-\mathrm{i}\hbar\alpha_{ij}g^{jk}\beta_{k\ell}\chi^{\ell i} .$$

The presence of the metric $g^{jk}$ on the right-hand side of (2) is due to the CAR (1), which leads to uncertainty in measuring the observables $A$ and $B$ simultaneously.

--

$^1$ In this answer, bosonic (fermionic) will mean Grassmann-even (Grassmann-odd), respectively.

Comment: Ah, this is interesting (both the question and the answer); I never brooded about an uncertainty principle involving fermionic operators. Dear Qmechanic, could you write an additional line such that I can explicitely see how the anticommutators of the fermionic constituents of A and B are linked to the uncertainty?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Hey thanks Qmechanic, if I could I would +1 once again :-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I only have time to skip it over at the moment so i'll comment if I have further questions about your answer.